# Loading style (*.qml file) to layer via PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, style, qml, coding-style

Is there any way to load a *.qml file to layer and set a style to it in python (pyqgis)?

Can I 'get into' this file in console? I want to review it.

Comment: Thank you @xunilk! This worked for me once I put these lines of code into the Python Console's Script editor, and ran the script. I am new to using Python in QGIS so more experienced users would probably not need to know that.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/137830)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have my qml styles in a fix path (c:/pyqgis_data/Styles/). So, to load **arrows_red_orange.qml** (exclusively for point layers), next lines at the Python Console of QGIS work:

```
>>>layer = iface.activeLayer()
>>>if layer.geometryType() == QGis.Point:
>>>...layer.loadNamedStyle('c:/pyqgis_data/Styles/arrows_red_orange.qml')
>>>layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: Thank you @xunilk. Do you know if I can 'review' or open this *.qml file in console?

Comment: Yes, you can. It is a markup language xml type.

Comment: You should use QgsWkbTypes.PointGeometry instead of QGis.Point in QGIS 3.x